# Visual Studio, Debugger, Step over run through breakpoints after stepped in another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I'm having problems debugging when I try to "step in" to classes.

I got multiple class in my CS solution. When I run the debug, it works fine in the ran class. Then I step in one instruction that comes from an other class. There, step over/in doesn't work anymore, it just stops through breakpoints.

I tried reset settings, repair VS, "Just my code" and "Enable property evaluation[...]" options, nothing better.

What should I do to get the F10/F11 works fine at anytime, anywhere in the solution ?

PS: I have my work committed under SVN and made some renaming in the same period this issue came out.

Comment: The compiler generate a pdb file which contains debugging information that VS uses during debug.  So you are not getting the debug information from 2nd project.  The second project dll gets copied into the main project bin folder.The location is specified in the main project csproj file.So I would open the csproj file of main project to see where the dll get copied from.I suspect a few thing may be happening.1) You are referencing the 2nd project Release Folder instead of the Debug folder 2) The 2nd project has been updated and the latest dll from 2nd project is not being used in main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was in a specific partial class. It is a xsd.exe generated class, which has written the attribute

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
```

on every methods. Here is the trouble source.